# Error when publishing ASP.NET Web API to Azure over Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2015 to publish a simple ASP.NET Web API to Azure over "Publish..." --> Microsoft Azure App Service. I choose to create all new service plan and resource but the deployment failed with MissingRegistrationForLocation error.

[image: Error]

Error on Azure portal:

Type
microsoft.insights/components
Resource Id
/subscriptions/8e45263d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3578972e80c4/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/components/xxx
StatusMessage
{
  "error": {
    "code": "MissingRegistrationForLocation",
    "message": "The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'components' in the location 'Central US'. Please re-register for this provider in order to have access to this location."
  }
}

Microsoft Azure annouces a [breaking change](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/application-insights-general-availability-in-additional-regions-and-resource-location-update-east-us-south-central-us-west-europe-and-north-europe/) but I don't know what I should do to make the Publish... function of Visual Studio work again. Apparently the template of Visual Studio is still not updated with this change but where I can edit the Azure template for Visual Studio?
Thank you.

EDIT: Download and install latest Azure SDK will solve the problem https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Download and install latest Azure SDK will solve the problem

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

The answer is also mentioned in the original post, but it took me an hour to discover this, so for others I pasted it as an answer.